# Is there a quick way to create a series of point text objects in Adobe Illustrator with sequentially increased numbers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, illustrator-scripting, numbering

For a simple game design, I find myself needing numbers in a consistent style, all of them single point text objects. Importing a text file creates a single text frame, and that's not what I want.

Is there a way to create a set amount of point text objects, with numerals increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this old script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnwun/js4ai/master/divideTextFrame.js) on GitHub by user [johnwun](https://github.com/johnwun). It still works in recent version of Illustrator as far as I can tell.

- Download the script.
- Import or manually enter a list of numbers divided by ordinary line breaks.
- Make sure the text is *Point Type*. Perhaps you need to use *Type > Convert To Point Type*.
- With the text selected, run the script using *File > Scripts > Other Scripts*.

---

If you need to generate a list of numbers you could run a script like this in your browser's console and copy/paste the result:

```
let from = 0;
let to = 40;
let numbers = "";
for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
  numbers += i + "\n";
}
console.log(numbers);
```

---

In InDesign I would perhaps use linked text frames with a *Paragraph Style*  with *Numbering* and *Keep Options* that makes sure to switch frame every paragraph.

Or if the numbers appear on separate pages I would simply use the *Current Page Number* marker.

Comment: Thanks, Wolff. I was already afraid the solution would be a script. I always have to look up how I run those in Ai ^^'

Comment: @Vincent, you're welcome. I don't think using scripts in Ai is user friendly. It's annoying that you have to browse for the script every time. Not sure if there's a way around that.